# Extract terms from a FASTA header

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I need to parse the FASTA header for the following terms: leaves, buds, stems, and tender shoots and  If a sequence contains any one of the terms, then I open a file and place it there using Biopython.

So I have converted them to a dictionary using `SeqIO.to_dict`:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
records_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("my_example.fasta","fasta"))
```

But now I don't know how to get the terms from the header. The sequences look like this:

```
>gi|393741877|gb|FS945568.1|FS945568 FS945568 tea plant lateral roots cDNA library Camellia sinensis cDNA clone LR29G09, mRNA sequence
CCGGGGATCCATTCCAAAATTCATCATAAACCTCTCAATATTGTTCACTTGAAAAAAGATGA...

>gi|393741878|gb|FS945569.1|FS945569 FS945569 tea plant lateral roots cDNA library Camellia sinensis cDNA clone LR29G11, mRNA sequence
CCGGGGGCTATCGAGCACTCACCGACTCACTCGAGAGCTAATACAGTCCACAGC...

>gi|393751846|gb|FS959695.1|FS959695 FS959695 tea plant young leaves cDNA library Camellia sinensis cDNA clone YL16A05, mRNA sequence
CCAACAACTTCTTCCTAACACTACCACCTTCTGTCAACTTACTTCTCCAAAGGCTTCTTTCTTCCACCAT
GGCTGCTTCTACCATGGCTCTCTCTTCCCCATCTTTCGCCGGAAAGGCGGTGAAACTTGCCCCGGAG...

>gi|393751847|gb|FS959696.1|FS959696 FS959696 tea plant young leaves cDNA library Camellia sinensis cDNA clone YL16A06, mRNA sequence
GAAACTGCATATAGAAAATCTCACTACCACTCTCTTCCTCTTCCTCTCTATCTTTCCTACCAAAGAAAG...

>gi|393750830|gb|FS956287.1|FS956287 FS956287 tea plant terminal buds cDNA library Camellia sinensis cDNA clone TB26G04, mRNA sequence
AGGATCGCACGGCCTTTGTGCCGGCGACGCATCATTCAAATTTCTGCCCTATCAACTTTCGATGGTAGGA
TAGT...

>gi|393750831|gb|FS956288.1|FS956288 FS956288 tea plant terminal buds cDNA library Camellia sinensis cDNA clone TB26G05, mRNA sequence
TCCCACAAACATGTTGCTCTCATCTTTCCAGTAAAAGATAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAACAAAGCAG...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert to a dictionary - you need the description from each defline (using `to_dict()` makes only the `id` the key).

The description is just a string, in which you can search for terms.
Break up records by category (potentially with each record belonging to more than one category), then save to file with `SeqIO.write()`:

```
import os
from Bio import SeqIO

records = SeqIO.parse("my_example.fasta", "fasta")

terms = ["leaves", "buds", "stems", "tender shoots"]
categorized_records = {term: [] for term in terms}

for record in records:
    for term in terms:
        if term in record.description:
            categorized_records[term].append(record)

for term, records in categorized_records.items():
    fasta_out = "%s.fasta" % term
    SeqIO.write(records, fasta_out, 'fasta')  # Will overwrite file
```